# Update statement in Sql based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
Task    Status             Date                  Flag

a   Complete    February 21, 2014   
b   In Progress February 11, 2014   
c   Complete    February 11, 2014   
d   Complete    February  1, 2014   
a   In Progress February 30, 2014          To remove
c   Not started February 12, 2014          To remove
b   Complete    February 13, 2014
```

I need to update the **Flag** column in the above table with a comment **("To remove" )** for all the records that have (In progress/Not started)
for the same task, (same task)
a status for every other ,except complete
Example:
Task "a" shows up twice (or multiple times, but only twice in my example).
The first time it shows in Feb 21 with Completed state.
The second time it shows with In Progress on a later date (Feb 30).
So the second occurrence must be marked for removal.

In case we had "a", "Not Started", Feb 2nd - this would be kept.

ps. dates are loaded in the db as date type

Comment: Post some of your code, what you have tried till now?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: When for a task, there is a second date, then descending date columns must be must be marked with false? As comment will be to remove for the second (descending date). Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following code, I have considered table name as tblTask.

```
With CTE as 
(
select task,status,DATE,flag,RANK() over (partition by task order by date asc, status  asc)  as Rnk
from tblTask
), CTE1 as
(
select * from CTE where
Rnk = 1 and status = 'Complete'
), CTE2 as
(
select tblTask.* from CTE1
left join tblTask on CTE1.task = tblTask.task
where tblTask.status <> 'Complete'
)
update  CTE2 set flag = 'To remove'
```

Will try for shortest method.